# Can Tableau Reader read workbooks that access their data via a link to a web-exposed server?

Tags: linked-list, tableau-api

Can Tableau Reader read Tableau workbooks that accesses its data via a link to a web-exposed server? I'm trying to work out if I can store data on a web exposed database server, build workbooks for people using Desktop professional on the data sitting on that server, and then send the workbooks to clients who have Tableau Reader. I understand those clients will only be able to access the canned reports I've embedded in the workbooks but will they be able to access the data on the server or does Reader required the data to be embedded in the workbook?

Comment: I believe you Tableau Reader does not connect to external databases. But it's not hard to test, create the twbx and open it in Tableau Reader. I'm away from my PC that has Tableay to test, but I can do it tomorrow

Comment: And in case you don't know, you can extract your data and then create the twbx, which will contain all the data. http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/sending-packaged-workbook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tableau Reader can only open Tableau packaged workbooks (.twbx files). The data needs to be embedded in the workbook in the form of a flat file (Excel, Access, CSV), a local cube or a Tableau Data Extract file. Whilst other types of data source can be saved in a .twbx file, it will not be possible to open such a .twbx file in Tableau Reader.

As Inox suggested, the best option would be to extract the data and create the packaged workbook that way. If it is not possible to extract the data, then Tableau Server or Tableau Online would be required to share those workbooks.